# HTML5 video and audio single source

Tags: javascript, html, audio, video, media

So I found some `HTML5` media player online so I can setup a home streaming network.. Easy enough but all my videos are in a single `.mp4` file and when I try to play a video with the `HTML5/JS` player it only plays the audio. Before I tried to play my video I noticed there where 3 sources for the example video, an `mp4`, `webm` and `ogg`.

I cant seem to find anything on google about it. How can I play audio and video from the same source with the `HTML5` player?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a video file where the browser supports the container format, video codec and audio codec.

It sounds like the video codec you are using in your mp4 files is not supported by your browser.

Three sources are provided in the example you found so that browsers with support for different container formats will get different video files. No browser will multiplex the three files together.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the info. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats says that mp4 video and audio work in Chrome which is what im using.

Comment: @user3291955.. Please try this test: http://html5test.com/ . This would highlight why a video file is not being played in your browser